# How do I test board components when check pins are available?

Tags: circuit-analysis, pcb-design, voltage-measurement

edit: The expected values and higher resolution images are linked below. [Higher Res Board Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbBAk.jpg) [Acceptable Values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbhdw.jpg)

I am a novice at board repair. I am repairing an instrument in a research lab where I conduct environmental chemistry research. The instrument uses combustion and spectroscopy to analyze dissolved organic carbon in a liquid sample.

Unfortunately, the instrument is experiencing numerous issues. One possible source of these issues is  the board which controls the spectroscopy process. The board is built with board check pins installed, and to confirm the functioning of the board I must use a multi-meter to test the voltage at these pins while powered.

Before I dive in, and likely break something, I am hoping someone with any experience in this could provide pointers and guidance.

[image: Board check pins are labeled "TP #" and are large brass stand outs with holes]

For each board check pin I was given an acceptable voltage value and instructions to test the pins while the power in on. I do have a basic multimeter.

What setting do I use on the multimeter? Are boards like this AC or are they converted to DC?

[image: Multimeter]

Any advice will be helpful.

Comment: *I am a novice at board repair.* and *What setting do I use on the multimeter? Are boards like this AC or are they converted to DC?* really makes me want to advice you to learn a bit more about electronics before trying to fix anything. The answers below tell you how to use that multimeter but that will not help you much. Suppose the meter says some voltage is 7 V, how will you know if that is correct or not? For that you need to be able to understand what a circuit is doing. Ideally you would have a **service manual** that tells you what should be measured on any testpoint.

Comment: You need to know how the board works in order to trouble-shoot it. Do you have a schematic? If you don't even know if you are about to measure AC or DC then you probably don't have much hope in succeeding. (Hint: unless it is a mains voltage power supply you are measuring, it is almost certainly VDC. And beginners should not go anywhere near VAC.) Most often you troubleshoot PCBs with an oscilloscope. The multimeter is often too crude since it can only measure fixed voltages and it can't measure time either. You need the multimeter to measure things like resistance and contact though.

Comment: Random note: the component "F10" lower right corner may or may not be poorly soldered. Looks fishy but the picture isn't high resolution enough to tell for sure.

Comment: Agree with Lundin's observation about F10. The soldering on that component, and a few others too I think, looks suspicious. It might just be an artifact of how you took the pic though - maybe you can post a clearer, higher resolution one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, these are *designed* to be measured while the equipment is running.

The test points are typically DC. If your guide says for example "7 V" it means 7 volts DC, and you should set your meter to the "V= 20". 20 is the upper range, and should be comfortably higher than what you expect. Don't put it on "2" if you expect 2 volts.

But voltages are measured *between* two points, so you need to find a ground reference. Hopefully the guide that tells you about the voltages also shows where the ground reference is, otherwise you can gamble and try the metallic part of the plated screw hole shown in the bottom right of your image.

Some of the test points may be expected to show more complex waveforms than just a simple fixed voltage. To check these you normally need an oscilloscope.

Comment: I should have included I have board check pin values to test. (https://imgur.com/a/Dwehohm) From this it seems to me the reference is TP9.

Comment: @pabstack Ok, that's pretty clear, they all seem to be DC voltages.

Comment: Done! Found a negative voltage between the check point and the common point, which does not match the voltage given. Ordered a new board with confidence! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You will need two probes. Connect one to red port (mAV ohm) on the right and one to the black port in the center. Set the dial to the V20 marking on the right of the dial. You will then connect the probe connected to the black port (COM) to a ground. I suggest using the mounting hole surrounded by the silver color at the bottom right of the board next to component F10. Touch the probe connected to the red port to each test point one at a time while holding the probe connected to the COM port on your ground and record your reading.